# How to protect a route from being accessed when logged in?

Tags: angularjs, routes, firebase

I have this error handling function which responds to errors in the routing, and redirects the user to the landing page if the user is **not** authenticated:

```
core.run(['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(event, next, previous, error) {
    if (error === 'AUTH_REQUIRED') {
      $location.path('/');
    }
  });
}]);
```

Now I want to reverse this, so that if the user is authenticated, this route is not available:

```
.when('/', {
  templateUrl: 'views/pages/landing.html',
  resolve: {
    'isAuth': ['fbRefs', function(fbRefs) {
      return fbRefs.getAuthObj().$waitForAuth();
    }]
  }
})
```

How would I alter the `resolve` above to check if the user **is** authenticated and if so, redirect to `/home` instead of `/`?

I tried manually rejecting the promise returned from the resolve but that makes the route disabled no matter if the user is authenticated or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle it manually with $q

```
.when('/', {
  templateUrl: 'views/pages/landing.html',
  resolve: {
    'isAuth': ['fbRefs', function(fbRefs, $q) {
      var onLoggedIn = function() {
        return $q.reject('NO_AUTH_REQUIRED');
      }

      var onLoggedOut = function(fbData) {
        return fbData;
      }

      return fbRefs.getAuthObj().$requireAuth()
        .then(onLoggedIn, onLoggedOut);
    }]
  }
})
```

...

```
core.run(['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(event, next, previous, error) {
    if (error === 'AUTH_REQUIRED') {
      $location.path('/');
    } else if (error === 'NO_AUTH_REQUIRED') {
      $location.path('/home');
    }
  });
}]);
```

Comment: Seems to work. Can you just explain the .then(onLoggedIn, onLoggedOut)? Thought then only had one parameter and that would be the response?

Comment: Take a look at the "The Promise API" section of https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q. It explains what you can pass to `then`

Comment: Ah so it's just a success/error callback, thanks :) Congrats on 5k :P

Comment: yep. Thanks for putting me over the edge!

Comment: There is also the ability to protect paths and data with user authentication.  See the documentation https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html